# AJAX jsTree with the checkbox plugin enabled, load child nodes when checked

Tags: jstree

In the case of a AJAX jsTree instance using the "checkbox" plugin, how can I make the following scenario happen?

When checking a node, make the tree load it's sub-nodes via AJAX.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided `tie_selection` is set to `false` and you have the tree configured to lazy load properly via AJAX (`core.data` should be a valid AJAX config) you can do this:

```
$('#tree').on('check_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    data.instance.load_node(data.node);
});
```